# Last.fm Scrobbler is not recognizing Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, last.fm-client

I am currently logged-in in both the Last.fm website and the last.fm Scrobbler installed on my desktop, but the Scrobbler doesn't seem to recognize my Rhythmbox plays, I have the Last.fm plugin option checked on my Rhythmbox's Preferences but when I click on 'Log in' on the Last.fm tab on Rhythmbox, it opens a new Firefox instance, I assume it is for me to log-in into my Last.fm account on that Firefox session but after I do that, nothing changes, the *'Waiting for authentication...'* message just freezes there, I think nothing is really being done with that:

[image]

I can perfectly log-in in both the Last.fm website and the Scrobbler on my desktop, but it doesn't seem to recognize Rhythmbox at all:

[image]

What can I do to make Rhythmbox know that I am actually already logged in and/or to make the Last.fm Scrobbler know that I am listening to music on my Rhythmbox player?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No that I know of but I'm not using the standard Firefox release either, I'm using Firefox Developer Edition as my default browser, and the *'Log in'* button on the *Last.fm* tab on Rhythmbox opens a new Firefox Developer Edition session; Every time I click the *'Log in'* button a new FDE window pops up, instead of just opening another tab in the same FDE session as I think it does when you're using the standard Firefox browser.